# compare two objects using underscore and replace the common values with one object

Tags: underscore.js

I want to compare two objects and create a new one .If the property in one object is not there it should be replaced by other object otherwise should not change

Comment: Can you add an example?

Comment: Does this work for you? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: here is the sample

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1pt2fc?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @TheHeadRush hey thanks worked !!!!!! so short and so simple !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let result = this.monthobj.map(el=>{
    this.monthobj2.forEach(ele=>{
      if(el.month == ele.month && el.value != ele.value){
        el.value = ele.value;
      }
    })
    return el;
  })
```

Updated answer : [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jdgj4z?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: hi your answer seems to be hold good for object but what if i have array of object with multiple properties ??
can you please go through the stackblitz link !!